# How to access the URL of a GET AJAX request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, get, forms

I had a look at some other questions but I'm still not sure how to achieve this.

The situation is I had a complex form that worked fine statically but I 'made it better' by making it submit using an AJAX request.

Now the url of the page doesn't change to have the parameters in it like before but I can see the fully qualified url using firebug.

What I am aiming to do is get this url and make a button to link to it so that the user can bookmark it because at the moment search results cannot be bookmarked.

Sorry if this is in anyway an exact duplicate but any help and advice is greatly appreciated.

This is my AJAX request(s) (they are basically the same but I have two forms presented as one form to the user, a simple search and a toggled advanced search) :

```
// setup AJAX request for simple search
$simpleform = $('#search');
$simpleform.submit(function() {
    $.ajax($simpleform.attr('action'), {
        data: $simpleform.serialize(),
        dataType: 'html',
        url: 'docsearch.php',
        type: 'GET', 

        beforeSend: function() {
            var $load = $('#loadingmessage');
            $('#search_results').fadeOut(1000);
            $load.hide().fadeIn(1000);

            if (!$load.length)
            {
                $load = $('<div id="loadingmessage">').appendTo($('#placeholder'));
            }

            $load.html('Searching... Please wait...');

            // disable both search buttons
            $('.submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $('.submit').addClass("disabled");

            $('#advancedsearchbutton').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $('#advancedsearchbutton').addClass("disabled");
        },

    success: function(response) {
        // response is the text sent back by server

        // find the search_results div in the response and insert it after the placeholder div
        $(response).find('#search_results').insertAfter($('#placeholder')).fadeIn(1000); 
        // re-initialise lightbox and dataTable plugins
        $('a.lightbox').lightBox();
        $('#test-docs-table').dataTable( {
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "sDom": 'Rlfrtip',
                "aoColumns": [
                    null,
                    null,
                    { "sType": "title-numeric" },
                    null
                ]
        });
    },

    complete: function() {
        // hide loading message:
        $('#loadingmessage').fadeOut('slow');

        // enable both search buttons
        $('.submit').removeAttr("disabled");
        $('.submit').removeClass("disabled");

        checkDropdowns();
    }
});

return false; // Cancel default event
});
// end AJAX request

// setup AJAX request for advanced search
$form = $('#advancedsearchform');
$form.submit(function() {
    $.ajax($form.attr('action'), {
        data: $form.serialize(),
        dataType: 'html',
        url: 'docsearch.php',
        type: 'GET', 

        beforeSend: function() {
            var $load = $('#loadingmessage');
            $('#search_results').fadeOut(1000);
            $load.hide().fadeIn(1000);

            if (!$load.length)
            {
                $load = $('<div id="loadingmessage">').appendTo($('#placeholder'));
            }
              $load.html('Searching... Please wait...');

            // disable both search buttons
            $('.submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $('.submit').addClass("disabled");

            $('#advancedsearchbutton').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $('#advancedsearchbutton').addClass("disabled");
        },

    success: function(response) {
        // response is the text sent back by server

        // find the search_results div in the response and insert it after the placeholder div
        $(response).find('#search_results').insertAfter($('#placeholder')).fadeIn(1000); 
        // re-initialise lightbox and dataTable plugins
        $('a.lightbox').lightBox();
        $('#test-docs-table').dataTable( {
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "sDom": 'Rlfrtip',
                "aoColumns": [
                    null,
                    null,
                    { "sType": "title-numeric" },
                    null
                ]
        });
    },

    complete: function() {
        // hide loading message:
        $('#loadingmessage').fadeOut('slow');

        // enable both search buttons
        $('.submit').removeAttr("disabled");
        $('.submit').removeClass("disabled");

        $('#advancedsearchbutton').removeAttr("disabled");
        $('#advancedsearchbutton').removeClass("disabled");
    }
});

return false; // Cancel default event
});
// end AJAX request
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why this is even a question. The URL of the HTTP request is the first argument to `$.get()`. In this case, it's the value returned by

```
$('#search').attr('action');
```

and

```
$('#advancedsearchform').attr('action');
```

respectively.

Perhaps I'm missing something here?

---

#### Edit:

> how to utilise the string that is being returned? i.e. to begin with, print it anywhere on the page.

You can stuff the string inside of a jQuery object, and then append it somewhere:

```
var action = $('#search').attr('action'),
    $span = $('<span/>', {text: action});

$('#placeholder').after($span);
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried to print this out to the page to see what it contains by doing the following: `$('#search').attr('action').insertAfter($('#placeholder'));` but this breaks my page...

Comment: That is because `.attr()` returns a string, not a jQuery object, so there is no `insertAfter()` method defined. This sort of problem is easy to find using a debugger - are you using one? If not, you really should.

Comment: ah, I see what you mean now. Hmm, in that case - how to utilise the string that is being returned? i.e. to begin with, print it anywhere on the page. I am thinking if I can modify the url from docsearch.php?blahblah to staticdocsearch.php (which will be almost the same page but a static form instead of an ajax one) with all the parameters then this could work.

Comment: thank you very much, don't want to be a pest but it doesn't seem to output anywhere on the page. I thought that perhaps the comma after the first line of your edit was meant to be a semi-colon perhaps but that didn't change anything. I will keep working on it though and try appending it elsewhere.

Comment: No, the comma is not meant to be a semicolon.

Comment: ok, not quite sure why that is though. Tried `after(), insertAfter(), appendTo()` and numerous locations but still can't get it to print anywhere on the page.

Comment: Are there any error messages that appear in the console? Could you post a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that shows what you're trying to do?

Comment: no errors that I can see, is this enough code - doesn't do anything in that context though. http://jsfiddle.net/n49n8/

Comment: There's no HTML in the fiddle. Of course it's not going to do anything.

Comment: will do it just now, wasn't sure if you wanted it or not.

Comment: this is with the php included but it needed stripped out obviously: http://jsfiddle.net/n49n8/1/ so this is what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/n49n8/6/

Comment: I just had a quick glance at the code; there is no element in your HTML with id `navbar`.

Comment: yeah, sorry i removed that from the fiddle since it had some private info in it so thought it was best to remove the div entirely.

Comment: Most of the code in the fiddle doesn't run because of `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'mbTooltip'`. In the `HTML` pane, jsFiddle expects only the markup in the `<body>`, not the full HTML. I'm going to keep slogging through this, but next time, ***please*** try to provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: The forms do not have `action` attributes, so `$('#search').attr('action')` returns `undefined`. That is why you're not seeing anything when you append `$span`. Even if you use an empty action attribute, like `<form action="" ...>` (which is another way to make the form submit to the current page), `$('#search').attr('action')` will return the empty string, not the URL of the current page, so again, you're not going to see what you expect when you try to dump the `action` onto the page.

Comment: apologies, I'm using so many plug-ins that I forgot to bits and bobs out. This should be cleaner: http://jsfiddle.net/n49n8/9/

I left out the action tag because the form was being sent through ajax but I did have it previously when the form was submitting to the same page.

Is there no way to achieve what I am trying to do then?

Comment: What _are_ you trying to achieve? What URL _should_ the form be submitted to? Omitting a form's `action` is not the right way to ajaxify a form. An actionless form is submitted to the current page. You can get the URL using [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location). If the forms need to get submitted to a different URL, you need to include the `action` attribute. This is especially important for users who browse with JavaScript disabled. When ajaxifying forms, to prevent normal form submission, just `return false;` from the `.submit()` callback.

Comment: Recommended reading: [How would I use jQuery to ajaxify a form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042996). Or just [use the plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/).

Comment: what i want to do is get the url of the get request, e.g. `docsearch.php?dosearch=true&filetype=any&filename=&filesize_min=&filesize_max=&numresults=10&orderbyad=ascending&orderby=id&outputformat=table&outputlocation=link` but the way my form is, the url of my browser window doesn't change as it would with a form submitted normally using the get method because the form is submitted using ajax.

Comment: You can build the query string using [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/).

Comment: yip, that's what I use already. If I add `docsearch.php` as the action of the form then it breaks. Completely confused now.

Comment: What breaks? What's confusing? The URL is the form's action, concatenated with the serialized form: `$('#search').attr('action') + '?' + $('#search').serialize()`.

Comment: ah I get what you mean now. Didn't think that you could use serialize like that. By breaking I mean I get no search results because of a 404 - not found error.

Comment: no idea what was wrong with that, i went back to a working version and re-made some changes and finally got it to print. must have had a bit of erroneous code. Thanks for all you're help, I *think* I'm ok from here.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you might consider returning the fully-qualified URL (with parameters) as part of your response, and then handle that within the `success:` block.

Comment: I would recommend a JSON-formatted response.  It appears you are returning the HTML for the search results, correct?  So all you need to do is return JSON with 2 objects:  the URL string and the HTML string.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll want to use [deep linking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_linking) to help you link directly to search results. You could use the query string if you want (i.e. `domain.com/search.php?q=Whatever`) but it might make more sense to use a hash and decode that instead (i.e. `domain.com/search.php#q=Whatever`).

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for an easy way to bookmark the page through script but every browser handles it differently and it might cause you more harm than good. Deep-linking is a nice solution to making dynamic pages bookmark-able, but with all your varying search parameters I can't imagine it being very easy to implement..  I would just have a button or a link you can press that reloads the same page with querystring parameters attached, so I'd say that you're on the right track.

I would do what @Keith recommends but, since bookmarking pages is a client-side issue, I would piece together the url on the client-side, within the 'success' handler.

Answer (score 1):

jQquery passes the original XHR object to event handlers. You can make use of it. In your case it might be something like this:

```
success: function(response, status, hxr) {
    var whereFrom = xhr.responseXML.baseURI;

    (...)
}
```